# AJAX responseText from php not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make a user registration form using AJAX, I'm fairly new to this so I don't have much experience in what I'm doing. My problem is not getting the php to work or the AJAX to send off the file it's the that responseText has no value when it comes back. I want it so that the responseText will be the PHP echo's. I think I'm along the right lines of what to do maybe? Help please. Also sorry for bad layout of the question, I'll tidy it up soon.

HTML:

```
<div id="registration">
    <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="formValidate()">
        <!-- Apply Javascript for form validation and change password property -->
        <div id="title">First Name:</div>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="First Name"/>
        <div id="title">Surname:</div>
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="Surname"/>
        <div id="title">Address:</div>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="Address Line 1"/>
        <input type="text" id="town_city" name="town_city" value="Town/City"/>
        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="Postcode" />
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="Country" />
        <div id="title">Email:</div>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email" />
        <div id="title">Password:</div>
        <input  type="text" name="password" id="password" value="Password" />
        <div id="title">Verify Password:</div>
        <input type="text" name="vPassword" id="vPassword" value="Passwloord" />
        <div id="status"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function formValidate() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xml = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    var url = 'php/validateUser.inc.php';
    var fn = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var ln = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    var add = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var tc = document.getElementById('town_city').value;
    var pCode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;
    var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var vPass = document.getElementById('vPassword').value;
    var userInput = "firstname=" + fn + "&surname=" + ln + "&address=" + add + "&town_city=" + tc + "&postcode=" + pCode + "&country" + country + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + pass + "&vPassword=" + vPass;

    xml.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xml.open('POST', url, true);

    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xml.readyState == 4) {
            if (xml.status == 200) {
                var return_data = xml.responseText;
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
            } else {
                alert("GNAH!");
            }
        }

        xml.send(userInput);
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Processing....";
    }
```

After I done this part I want the echo's of the PHP to appear in the status div but they appear in the left hand corner of the screen, yet the "Processing...." doesn't. Any suggestions please I know this is the file that's wrong.

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['surname'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['town_city'], $_POST['postcode'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['vPassword'])) {
        $fName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
        $lName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
        $addr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
        $town_city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['town_city']);
        $pCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
        $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $pass_hash = md5($pass);
        $vPass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vPassword']);

        if (!empty($fName) && !empty($lName) && !empty($addr) && !empty($town_city) && !empty($pCode) && !empty($country) && !empty($email) && !empty($pass) && !empty($vPass) && $pass == $vPass) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `usertable` (user_id, fName, lName, Address, town_city, pCode, Country, Email, Password) VALUES ('', '$fName', '$lName', '$addr', '$town_city', '$pCode', '$country', '$email', '$pass')";
            $query_run = mysql_query($query);
            if ($query_run) {
                header('Location: login.php');
            } else {
                echo mysql_error();
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Please fill in all fiels and make sure both passwords match.';
        }
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you already tried replacing the PHP file's logic with a simple print statement to confirm that it is functioning as expected?

Comment: Try the PHP side with some temporary replacement `$_GET`s. This way you can see the result in the browser using parameters: `mypage.php?firstname=James&surname=Poulson` ...

Comment: I would look into jQuery... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: do you have any other element with `id="status"` in your html code?

Comment: Nope that's the only one. I tried to alert out the return_data function in the Javascript file and it seems to be empty yet I'm expecting it to have the php echo in there but it hasn't. :/

Comment: The only time the script echoes something is when there's an error. Is that the case you're testing? When the INSERT is successful, it redirects to login.php, and the return_data will be the entire contents of that page.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supplying a value for the "submit" form field in your `userInput` variable, so the test:

```
if ($_POST['submit'])
```

fails. Change the assignment to:

```
var userInput = "submit=Register&firstname="+fn+...
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the php file it works just fine, it adds the users and redirects straight away, just on the else statements when it echo's something out the echo appears in the top left. Yet I want the echo to appear in the div id="status" box using javascript.

Comment: @user1705000 normally when the form is submitted in usual way, the submit button value also being passed with the `$_POST` array, and this is what you were checking at first, but wont be passed with the ajax request unless you explicitly specify. Take a look on [Successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)